# Gatefold brochure for conference programme: graphics split on either side of paper?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a brochure for an upcoming academic conference. I would like to make this a gate-fold card, folded as shown below.

My challenge is the following: I want the front page to be not unlike in the illustration shamelessly borrowed from [uprinting](https://www.uprinting.com/gate-fold-brochure.html).
I could do this with tikz with absolute node positioning and copying the code to be repeated on either side of what will become the front page, but I wonder: Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

[image: gate fold]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem. Would you mind explain it better?

Comment: I'm sure you could do this in LaTex, but it really is not the right tool for the job. Use a good desktop publishing package instead.

Comment: I do not have access to such a tool, nor do I know how to use it. 

I ended up using minipages in tikz nodes positioned on absolute papert coordinates. Works well, is easy enough to do - and I did not have to pay for or learn a new tool for the job.